# adding Header & Footer to a Seaborn Line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'B': [200,300,400,800,1500],
                   })
df
    A   B
0   1   200
1   2   300
2   3   400
3   4   800
4   5   1500
```

I have created a line plot from this dataframe like with the code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white','grid.color': '#b0b0b0','axes.edgecolor': 'black'})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=3)

graph= sns.lineplot(data=df, x='A', y='B',ax=ax1)
graph.set_title("Title of the graph");
```

The graph looks like below now
[image]

However, I want a little bit more information on the graph based on the variable values I have.

The variables are

```
chartType = 'A vs B'
itemType = 'LMV'
PartNr='123456'
SerialNr = '789'
date='1.1.2022'

testLocation='Internal'
operator='king'
date='5.5.2022'
results-'C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop\results.xlsx'
testNUmber='test123'
```

I want these variable to be added to the graph like below. These variable are dynamically generated (I have just hard coded here for simplicity)

Is this even possible? If yes, please guide for at-least one variable & I will figure out the rest.

I thought annotation may help but since these variable need to be added 'outside' the graph, I was not sure it it was possible & was also wondering if there is a another way to do it. Thanks.

[image]

**Update**

I figured a 'hack' to get something close to what I want. It is has a couple of problems

a. **Too much code repetition**
b. The gaps at the top still exist & the gap to the main plot also needs adjusting

Does anyone have any idea to address these two issues? Code is as below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'B': [200,300,400,800,1500],
                   })

chartTypeV = 'A vs B'
itemTypeV = 'LMV'
PartNrV='123456'
SerialNrV = '789'
dateV='1.1.2022'

testLocationV='Internal'
operatorV='king'
dateV2='5.5.2022'
resultsV=r'C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop\results.xlsx'
testNUmberV='test123'

sns.set(rc={'axes.facecolor':'white','grid.color': '#b0b0b0','axes.edgecolor': 'black'})
gridShape=(18,6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 18))
chartType = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0, 0), colspan=1, rowspan=2)
chartType.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
chartType.xaxis.set_visible(False)
chartType.yaxis.set_visible(False)
chartType.text(0.5, 0.5, chartTypeV, va="center", ha="center")

itemType = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,1), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
itemType.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
itemType.xaxis.set_visible(False)
itemType.yaxis.set_visible(False)
itemType.text(0.5, 0.5, itemTypeV, va="center", ha="center")

PartNrHeading  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,3), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
PartNrHeading.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
PartNrHeading.xaxis.set_visible(False)
PartNrHeading.yaxis.set_visible(False)
PartNrHeading.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Part Nr.', va="center", ha="center")

PartNr  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (1,3), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
PartNr.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
PartNr.xaxis.set_visible(False)
PartNr.yaxis.set_visible(False)
PartNr.text(0.5, 0.5, PartNrV, va="center", ha="center")

SerialNrHeading  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,4), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
SerialNrHeading.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
SerialNrHeading.xaxis.set_visible(False)
SerialNrHeading.yaxis.set_visible(False)
SerialNrHeading.text(0.5, 0.5, 'SerialNr', va="center", ha="center")

SerialNr  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (1,4), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
SerialNr.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
SerialNr.xaxis.set_visible(False)
SerialNr.yaxis.set_visible(False)
SerialNr.text(0.5, 0.5, SerialNrV, va="center", ha="center")

dateHeading  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (0,5), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
dateHeading.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
dateHeading.xaxis.set_visible(False)
dateHeading.yaxis.set_visible(False)
dateHeading.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Date', va="center", ha="center")

date  = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (1,5), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
date.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False, labelright=False, labeltop=False)
date.xaxis.set_visible(False)
date.yaxis.set_visible(False)
date.text(0.5, 0.5, dateV, va="center", ha="center")

plotAxis = plt.subplot2grid(gridShape, (2, 0), colspan=6, rowspan=9)


#Graph is created and stored in the variable 'PCV_graph'
graph= sns.lineplot(data=df, x='A', y='B',ax=plotAxis)
graph.set_title("Title of the graph");
```

The plot look like this now

[image]

Comment: I was wondering if I could address this issue with a table or an annotation box. I can't include two rows within a row in a table and I can't control the column width as it would work with the axis labels on the columns. I would have to try the header section in the annotation box and calculate the additional whitespace according to the length of the string for each item. Even if I could do that I would not be able to get away from the tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works to a certain extent (the data is there but it is not 'aligned' as i would prefer). Nonetheless, thank for your time. I will try to explore further. If i find a solution, will share it as well.

Comment: I can't come up with any good ideas regarding this. I will delete my comment on the link, but if you have a good solution method, please answer your self.